# Put footnote between author name and year in Bibtex (chicago style)

Tags: bibtex, footnotes, natbib, chicago-style

I used "chicago.bst" as my "\bibliographystyle" for references and I use \citet{jon90} for a textual citation, as Jones et al. (1990).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\begin{document}
    This comes from \citet{goncalves2020physics}.
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

and `references.bib`:

```
@article{goncalves2020physics,
  title={A physics-based high-resolution BIPV model for building performance simulations},
  author={Goncalves, Juliana E and van Hooff, Twan and Saelens, Dirk},
  journal={Solar Energy},
  volume={204},
  pages={585--599},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

which gives the next output.

[image]

I need to have a footnote after the name of the author and before the year. I do not know how to do that automatically, but in the next manually I did it which is not my favorite because it is not linked to the references. How can I add footnote between author name and year by using`\citet`? Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}
\begin{document}
    This comes from Goncalves et al.\footnote{This work $\cdots$} (2020).
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: Be sure to encase "BIPV" in curly braces to keep BibTeX from converting it to lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`natbib`'s `\citet` and `\citep` macros are there to create "full" authoryear-style citation call-outs. The package also provides macros called `\citeauthor` and `citeyear` to output just the `author` and `year` components of a "full" authoryear-style citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{goncalves2020physics,
  title  ={A physics-based high-resolution {BIPV} model 
           for building performance simulations},
  author ={Goncalves, Juliana E. and van Hooff, Twan 
           and Saelens, Dirk},
  journal={Solar Energy},
  volume ={204},
  pages  ={585--599},
  year   ={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=magenta,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\setlength\textheight{2.25in}

\begin{document}

This comes from \citet{goncalves2020physics}.

This comes from \citeauthor{goncalves2020physics}\footnote{This work \dots}
(\citeyear{goncalves2020physics}).
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you need this often, you could even define a `\newcommand{\citefoot}[2]{\citeauthor{#1}\footnote{#2} (\citeyear{#1})}` which you could then use as `\citefoot{goncalves2020physics}{This work \dots}`.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Thank you.